# Running program in background

Tags: c, linux

Ive got my program in C, 6 source files, and the aim is to copy those files to any other Linux OS computer, and (probably compile, im newbie, so not sure what is needed here) run this program in background. Something like:

```
user@laptop:~$ program
```

> Program is running in a background. In order to stop Program, type
>   XXX.

Any tips on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `daemon(0,0);` call in your C program.

stopping it is a bit trickier, I suppose there is only one copy of the program running. Put the program's PID in a file, write another utility (`XXX`) which reads the PID from the file and kills it.

Important: `daemon` forks, get the PID of the program after calling daemon.

But maybe you are too newby and just want to execute your program with `program&` and later `kill` it.

Comment: Yes, I am too newbie to use the first way, but I need it do it like this. Could you please provide me a bit more information(more details, snippet of a code would be the best thing) about the first solution? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I completely missunderstood the question. You need shell scripting for this.

For file copying you can use `scp`. Execute command on the other host with `ssh`. It should be something like (not tested):

```
pid=`ssh user@host "make >/dev/null 2>&1; nohup ./program; echo $!`
```

later you can stop it with

```
ssh user@host "kill $pid"
```

Comment: No, you did not. The solution you postedd first is OK. I have the PID in a file, and im trying to use `kill()` and to kill the process, but I do not know what signal should I send. I tryed 0, not working, then I tried some `raise()` signals, but not working either. What should i use?

Comment: I'd try SIGQUIT before SIGTERM: it's a little more polite :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fork().

In parent, you should just exit, in child process - you should handle SIGHUP signal.

In such way - you have daemon.